# Sharing the effect

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, directx9

my problem is :

If I load 2 models ( the same model zombie ) and give them the same effect I got the following error :

```
        for(int i =0 ; i<2 ; i++)
        {
            dwarfModel[i].model = Content.Load<Model>("Models//dwarf//dwarfmodel");
            dwarfModel[i].effect = Content.Load<Effect>("Models//dwarf//skinFX");
            dwarfModel[i].setEffect(camera , game);
            dwarfModel[i].setModelAnimationStatus(game);
            dwarfModel[i].intializeChrachterController(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 20, 10, 2000, 2000, 80, 40);

            space.Add(dwarfModel[i].chrachterController);

            dwarfModels.Add(dwarfModel);
        }
enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: One of the meshes in the model is probably using a different Effect-type i.e. SkinnedEffect which cannot be cast into a BasicEffect.

Comment: Aaron Kabashi , so what is the solution ?? I must use the same effect ?? that's problem occured when I make 2 models of the same type , i.e Zombie share the same effect , but if I load monster.x and zombie.x and use the same effect then no problem !!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to call the Effect property of your ModelMeshPart you get an Effect instance and Effect is the base class for all effect. So you can't cast an Effect instance to a BasicEffect because BasicEffect inherits from Effect.

Furthermore you don't need to cast it to a BasicEffect.

Your line:

```
BasicEffect oldEffect = (BasicEffect)part.Effect;
```

Should be:

```
Effect oldEffect = part.Effect;
```

Comment: Takumi I will try in a moment